# Is there a way to create aws lambda execution role with cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, roles

I'm trying to create a lambda fuction with cloudformation but it requires a lambda execution role - is there a way I can generate one using cloudformation?

Comment: Have you reviewed [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, CloudFormation can be used to create an IAM role.  The lambda execution role is an IAM role like any other IAM role.  The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) for doing so shows this example:

```
MyRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties: 
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument: Json
    Description: String
    ManagedPolicyArns: 
      - String
    MaxSessionDuration: Integer
    Path: String
    PermissionsBoundary: String
    Policies: 
      - Policy
    RoleName: String
    Tags: 
      - Tag
```

Then in the lambda, you reference it using a ref to the name of the role resource.  Ex:

```
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Role: !GetAtt MyRole.Arn
```

Comment: A lambda execution role is not just a simple role, it contains an inline managed policy that is generated by aws when you create a lambda function. The problem is that on one hand you need that role to create the lambda function on cloudformation, and on the other hand the role is created only when you create the lambda function.

Comment: You can add managed policies to the IAM role that CloudFormation creates--the same policies that would get added if you have Lambda create the role using the console.  But the console _also_ allows you to pick an _existing_ role, so that is great evidence that the role is **not** created only when you create the lambda.  You don't _need_ to have lambda create the execution role.  I have many CloudFormation templates that create roles and then create lambdas that use those roles.  It is a common use case.

Comment: This has more detail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html#permissions-executionrole-console

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option creating the lambda via console because I need the cloudformation for a specific purpose. I do know that I can create a role using cloudformation and attaching rellavent policies but the question is - what are the rellavent policies I need for a role to be used by a lambda function? because via console the policy is generated by the system. I tried attaching the policies described in the document but i get this error: "Policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole does not exist or is not attachable."

Comment: Well, that is actually a different question than the one you asked. I'm not suggesting you create the lambda via the console, just citing that as evidence. If your lambda isn't accessing other services, you need to attach: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole  You can go to IAM and find the policy and copy the ARN from there to be sure you are using the correct one--the one you listed isn't the correct ARN.

Comment: You need "service-role" in the ARN: `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`

Comment: I am a bit confused @Shawn . I have tried the approach of your answer first, and it hasn't worked. Using the ARN (!GetAtt MyRole.Arn) works. In which scenario would the one in your answer work?

Comment: @AlexandroNadal You are right, I updated my answer.  The original version using !Ref would work if the role ARN is passed in as a parameter.  Thanks for noting it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IAM role with a role policy where it will take region and account id from predefined AWS FloudFormation variables and assign it to lambda elements in cloud formation. please refer following example

```
"Resources": {
    "AheadLambdaRole": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
        "Properties": {
            "RoleName": {
                "Fn::Sub": "AHEADLambdaRole-${EnvName}"
            },
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Action": [
                            "sts:AssumeRole"
                        ],
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": [
                                "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "Version": "2012-10-17"
            },
            "Policies": [{
                    "PolicyDocument" : {
                        "Version": "2012-10-17",
                        "Statement": [
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                                "Resource": {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "Effect": "Allow",
                                "Action": [
                                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                                ],
                                "Resource": [
                                    { "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/LambdaName:*"}
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "PolicyName" : "NameOfInlinepolicy"
                  }] 
         "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess",
                "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMFullAccess"
            ],
            "Path": "/"
        }
    }}
```